# Raw image data conversion in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, html5-canvas

I get a raw image data from a server, what are my best options to draw it on a canvas and how do I do it? Please give an insight as I am very new to html and javascript. All I want to know is how do I convert the raw data and draw it on a canvas in html and javascript, if I know the width and height of the raw image.Basically I dont know the format of the raw image i need to do some conversion.

Comment: Have you taken a look at [this](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp) page?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `context.createImageData` to create an imageData object which you can fill with your RGBA data from your server:

Example code an a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/XTATB/

```
// test data fill a 30x20 canvas with red pixels

// test width/height is 30x20
var canvasWidth=30;
var canvasHeight=20;

// resize the canvas 
canvas.width=canvasWidth;
canvas.height=canvasHeight;

// create some test data (you can use server data in production)
var d=[];
for(var i=0;i<canvasWidth*canvasHeight;i++){
    // red & alpha=255 green & blue = 0
    d.push(255,0,0,255);
}

// create a new imageData object with the specified dimensions
var imgData=ctx.createImageData(canvasWidth,canvasHeight);

// get the data property of the imageData object
// this is an array that will be filled with the test data
var data=imgData.data;

// copy the test data (d) into the imageData.data (data)
for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    data[i]=d[i];
}

// push the modified imageData object back to the canvas
ctx.putImageData(imgData,0,0);
```

Comment: how do i extract RGBA values from the raw image first?

Comment: Your question implied that you have already converted from RAW to a readable format. Raw files are not directly readable as RGB without conversion. Use a raw converter (as exists in many image processing apps) to read the raw files, apply adjustments and output the result to either a standard image format (.png, .jpg, etc) or get the RGB values.  Alternatively, you might check out if imageMagick supports conversion of your particular RAW file: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php

Comment: I am sorry its just a RAW image, edited the question accordingly

Comment: Did you check out imagemagick--it does convert some of the most common raw files?