# Convert framebuffer dump to image(bmp, png, etc.)

Tags: javascript, html, linux, framebuffer

I have a server where I am dumping the framebuffer data using `cat /dev/fb0 > fbdump.raw` and sending this file's contents to web client to display as a screenshot. Tried quite a few links before posting the question, but none helped in rendering an image on HTML/JS client side.

Is there any processing required on client side or is there any readymade API available for this in JavaScript? Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Referred Links:

- [How do I convert RGBA raw buffer to PNG file in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44177515/how-do-i-convert-rgba-raw-buffer-to-png-file-in-javascript) : Cannot use it as it uses node.js module.
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageBitmapRenderingContext/transferFromImageBitmap: Considers data in bitmap format.
- [Raw image data conversion in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23713912/raw-image-data-conversion-in-javascript) : Considers data already in readable format.

Comment: Please help us help you by providing us with what Stack Overflow posts you've looked at and found lacking. There are a lot of questions about taking byte arrays and rendering them as images, for instance. I'm guessing that you'll need to convert the raw data to a format displayable by the browser though (png, jpg, etc.). There is no built in API for that transformation.

Comment: Thanks. Edited the question with links mentioned.

Comment: It would be easier to just save the framebuffer as a png on the server using something like [fbgrab](https://github.com/GunnarMonell/fbgrab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put `ImageData` (raw RGBA image data stored in a `Uint8ClampedArray`) on a canvas.

You have to convert the framebuffer dump (BGRA) to RGBA by swapping red and blue.
Setting the alpha to 255 (opaque) is nececary as well, because the linux framebuffer doesn't use the alpha channel so it is usually 0 (transparent).

```js
fetch("fbdump.raw") // load the dump
.then(response => response.arrayBuffer()) // convert the response to a ArraBuffer
.then(array_buffer => {
    let canvas = document.querySelector("canvas") // get the canvas
    let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d") // get the context
    let raw_data = new Uint8ClampedArray(array_buffer) // use the ArrayBuffer as a Uint8ClampedArray for easier acces and the constructor of ImageData needs a Uint8ClampedArray
    for (let i = 0; i < raw_data.length; i += 4) {
        // convert the BGRA dump to RGBA
        let b = raw_data[i + 0]
        raw_data[i + 0] = raw_data[i + 2]
        raw_data[i + 2] = b
        raw_data[i + 3] = 255 // set alpha to 255 to make it non transparent (the alpha ist set to 0 and is unused in the linux framebuffer)
    }

    let image_data = new ImageData(raw_data, 1920, 1080) // create a new ImageData object with a resolution of 1920x1080

    // set the canvas resolution to 1920x1080
    canvas.width = 1920
    canvas.height = 1080

    ctx.putImageData(image_data, 0, 0) // puts the image on the canvas, starting at (0,0)
})
```

This code assumes the framebuffer has a resolution of 1920x1080 and the BGRA pixel format.

Comment: Sorry I did not answer my own question, but this was exactly what worked for me a few days back. Thank you for the entire code snippet.